# Android app only starts if phone connected to computer using usb cable

Tags: android

I am having strange issue.

I developed android application and deployed to android phone using usb cable.

App starts up only if phone is connected to computer using cable. After starting up, I can disconnect the cable and app still runs fine.

So seems like, for the app to boot up, it requires computer connection.

Any ideas why?

Below is my android manifest.

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.test"
              android:installLocation="auto" 
              android:versionName="0.5.14" 
              android:versionCode="33"
              >
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
      <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
                        android:largeScreens="true"
                        android:normalScreens="true"
                        android:smallScreens="true" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>

      <application android:icon="@drawable/bay"
                   android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"              
                  >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
          </intent-filter>
           <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
               android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
          </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HelpActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="user">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity" />
      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission
         android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Check if your app is waiting for attach a debugger. If there is a call to `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()` in the launch flow, then your app may be waiting

Comment: Bullseye!!!.. that worked...can you add as answer to this post, so i can accept and you can get points....thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to debug the earliest code of our apps, we use to add a call to `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()` which will keep our app waiting for a debugger attach.

There are situations in which we put that call in methods that block the activity's life cycle, such as `onCreate()`. In these cases, if the device is not connected, android can't attach to a debugger and kepps waiting forever.

So look for that call in your activity life cycle and remove it if found.